# Why the value of $_SESSION gets overwritten when the page is used from a new tab window?

Tags: php, session

I am very new to PHP, so excuse my ignorance. The problem I'm facing is with session variables, such as the following.

```
$_SESSION["input_file"] = $_REQUEST['selected_file'];
```

To test the web page I've made, I open the page from multiple tabs in the firefox browser, and click submit on each. But when I do so, the session variables are getting overriden in the older submits with the newer submits. Why each web page doesn't have a unique session associated with them?

Comment: If sessions were unique between page loads they'd be completely *useless*. They exist so data can persist *across* page loads.

Comment: So, what should I do for multiple users? How can make them unique for pages opened in different windows/browsers/computers?

Comment: For multiple users it's fine. Your issue is because you're looking at the same session in all the browser tabs of your browser. If you want to test multiple users, run different browsers at the same time and/or in incognito mode.

Comment: You mean If I access the page even from a different device, it would be unique? What about different browsers on the same computer?

Comment: They would count as different users. The session is unique between a browser/server connection

Comment: Where is the part `Javascript` and `JQuery` are flagged for?

Comment: `$_SESSION["input_file"][] = $_REQUEST['selected_file'];` it will create a session array which will not over-written by new values

Comment: What is the need for downvoting this. I said I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A session is identified by an ID, usually stored in a cookie. Since a browser session shares cookies over all tabs and windows, you have to create multiple browser profiles to get able to test a multiple user situation.

Comment: What do you mean across all windows. You mean if I open two firefox windows (not tabs on the same firefox window), I will also get the same problem?

Answer (score -1):

That because you are not checking whether the session variable is empty or not before assigning new value. You are just assigning the new value to it whenever the code get executed.

You need to do something like this

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["input_file"])){
    $_SESSION["input_file"] = $_REQUEST['selected_file'];
}
```

OR

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["input_file"])){
    $_SESSION["input_file"] = $_REQUEST['selected_file'];
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would solve the problem. The session variable would still be overwritten by the new tab window. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @pythonic create a session array instead of variable as i said in  y comment

Comment: @pythonic it won't and it doesn't the code is tested and the old value still exist in the session when the page is open in new tab.